# How to get email notifications for 'X upload Y' videos from subscribed channels?

Tags: youtube

I am subscribed to some channels and I have set notifications to 'All'. I am getting notifications from the YouTube app on my phone. I want to get the same notifications by email. Where's the setting for this? Under Email notification, these are my current settings.

[image]

Comment: [YouTube Help > Changes to emails you receive for new video uploads from your subscriptions](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/63269933?hl=en) (August 2020)